# split the end of the path in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, split

I have following string in my shell script.
**/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java**
What is the best way to split it into **/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre**

Comment: So you want to remove anything starting with `/bin/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`, if you can setup the input and output separators correctly, the solution becomes intuitive:

```
echo /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java | awk '{ NF -= 2 } 1' FS=/ OFS=/
```

Output:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre
```

#### Explanation

`awk` implicitly splits its input at the `FS` string (or pattern with some versions of `awk`). The number of fields is stored in the `NF` variable; subtracting two from `NF` results in leaving off the last two elements. The `1` at the end invokes the default code block: `{ print $0 }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh

path=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java 
short_path="${path%/bin*}" 
echo $short_path
```

More string manipulation examples here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an `awk` solution, one alternative is (similar in `sed`)

```
$ echo /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java | 
  awk '{sub("/[^/]+/[^/]+$","")}1'

/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre
```

note that this is generic in the sense that it will chop down the last two levels in the path.